# How to check which checkbox tag user clicked?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the rails,how the browser know which checkbox the user clicked?

```
=check_box_tag "name"
```

I checked on here 
they have http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {}),
```

can someone explain the logic above? and does it has function to save which checkboxtag user selected?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'function to save which checkboxtag user selected'? Are you trying to access the data in the browser, or on the server after form submission?

Comment: I want to let my server know which chickbox the user selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form items (including checkboxed) are identified by their name. As long as you wrap them in a form tag that submits to the desired route on your server, it's no different than any other form (user sign up, login, etc.). The checkbox data will be available in your controller in the params hash.

For example, this code in your view:

```
<%= form_tag("/checkboxes", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:box_1) %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:box_2) %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:box_3) %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:box_4) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

will allow you to access your checkboxes like this in the controller:

```
def checkboxes
  params[:box_1]
  params[:box_2]
  params[:box_3]
  params[:box_4]
end
```

Comment: i see, i just realize that in rails if you dont give them a name/id, they will assign a default value